# How to switch to system wide dark theme in i3 or sway?

Tags: linux, debian, firefox, i3, sway

On gnome, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'` can set dark theme system-wide.

However, the same doesn't happen with a sway session. Firefox browser still detects light theme.

Answer (score 17):

Firefox uses the GTK theme settings. On sway I could set the setting `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme` to `1` to get Firefox and GTK apps to use a dark theme by default.

You'll need to edit (or create if it doesn't exist) the following file:

`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

To look something like this:

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

After that firefox and GTK apps were dark by default. It will likely require a restart of the application in the case of them already running.

Comment: That does work, however I need to restart the application (firefox, in this case). Anyway to make changes without restarting?

Comment: This is a nice answer. nicotine+ also respects this, in case this comment helps someone searching (like I was).

Comment: Looks like this only works if the `gtk-theme-name` is set to a theme that has dark counterpart. ( Finding out which themes are installed is a whole another can of beans, on my Debian 11 with i3 it looks like `ls /usr/share/themes/` but that is probably not all, and some of themes there are not gtk-3 themes.)

Answer (score 1):

**lxappearance** works for me on i3 wm with linux mint

> lxappearance is a program to change GTK+ themes, icon themes, and
> fonts used by applications. It is a feature-rich
> GTK+ theme switcher.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you need to set theme (or rice) manually. there are tools that allow it to be more automated like pywall, but for your purposes, i believe you want to switch the icon and background theme. to do this i personally use lxappearance and qt5ct. I dont personally know how to change all themes of applications with only a window manager though.

If you want a video to help with this here is a good source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_Mid3_1Uzo